# Do magnetism and light interact with each other?

Tags: electromagnetism

If we bring along two types of energy magnetism and light.
Do they in any environment react with each other and cause any of them to be manipulated.Apparently light has a part of magnetism in it.

Comment: There's no such thing as "two types of energy." "magnetism" is not  a word, and light is E-M radiation.

Comment: Ok pal.Not really a physics person.These were the words I learnt in Science to describe my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - the [Faraday Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_effect), among others.
The Faraday effect causes a rotation of the plane of polarization in the medium through which it propagates, which is linearly proportional to the component of the magnetic field in the direction of propagation.

The intensity of the effect depends on the medium and field strength

Comment: Any suggestions to watch an experiment video online so I can better understand it.

Comment: Youtube has this one https://youtu.be/UFEVvsbvlkA and a few more related to the Faraday effect